# data.table filtering solution based on posixct datetime and two variables?

Tags: r, data.table, time-series

I have a data frame of when animals are detected at different sites. I want to eliminate rows (filter) from the detection file (df) for **only** site A if the individual animal wasn't detected at site B within a time frame ( 5 minutes). **I need to iterate this over every individual animal and across multiple sites**. my real data has many animals and over a million detection observations. I'm looking for a data.table solution to be efficient.

The two variables would be the individuals (animals) and the site detected.

Example:

```
obs.num<-1:21 # a simple observation number 
animal<-c(rep("RBT 1",10),rep("RBT 2",7) ,rep("RBT 3",2),"RBT 4","RBT 2") # 
a fake list of animal id's (my data has many)
now <- Sys.time()
ts <- seq(from = now, length.out = 16, by = "mins")
ts <- c(ts,seq(from=tail(ts,1), length.out = 3, by = "hour")) # create a 
fake series of time stamps 
ts <- c(ts,seq(from=tail(ts,1), length.out = 2, by = "hour"))
df<-data.frame(obs.num,animal,ts) # make data frame 
df$site<-c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","B")# make a fake series of sites detection occurred at 
str(df)
df # my example data frame
```

In this example i would like to remove the entire row for observation 19.

I'm looking for a data.table solution similar to this solution

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("with B as (select * from df where site == 'B')
  select distinct df.* from df 
  join B on df.animal = B.animal and 
        B.ts - df.ts between -5 * 60 and 5 * 60
  order by 1")
```

Comment: I'm not sure how your logic will scale up "across multiple sites", could you elaborate?

Comment: My real data has 12 sites . so eventually i want to be able to apply it further. for instance do the same thing and eliminate all "site C" that aren't detected within 10 mins of "site D".  for now I just need something that can be iterated across all individuals. I can always add multiple filtering steps for the other sites. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

A bit clunky, but you can accomplish this with non-equi-joins in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
nm = names(df)
# unfortunately non-equi-joins don't support on-the-fly
#   columns yet, so we have to first define them explicitly; see:
#   https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1639
df[ , ts_minus_5 := ts - 5*60]
df[ , ts_plus_5 := ts + 5*60]

# identify the observations _matching_ your criteria (i.e. those to keep)
found_at_b = unique(
  df[site == 'A'][df[site == 'B'], .(x.obs.num, x.animal),
                  on = .(animal == animal, ts >= ts_minus_5, ts <= ts_plus_5),
                  # allow.cartesian allows this join to return any
                  #   number of rows, necessary since any "B" row
                  #   might match multiple "A" rows;
                  # nomatch = 0L drops any "B" row without a 
                  #   match found in "A" rows
                  allow.cartesian = TRUE, nomatch = 0L]
)

# to filter, define a "drop" flag (could also call it "filter")
df[site == 'B', drop := FALSE]
df[found_at_b, on = c(obs.num = 'x.obs.num', animal = 'x.animal'),
   drop := FALSE]

# could define drop = TRUE for the other rows, but no need
df = df[(!drop)]
```

There are some other ways to clean the code up a bit by being more careful about potentially creating copies, perhaps `split`-ing the data by `site` first, doing as much as possible within one `[]` call, etc., but this will get you started.

Comment: thanks for you @MichaelChirico I think this is very close!  I do NOT want to drop any "B" rows. Can i simply remove the "nomatch = 0L"?  Also, in my real data i have many more sites (C,D,E,F, etc...)  do i need to go through all of them and do     df[site =='c', drop := FALSE]  to be able to keep them or would there be a quicker way?  using c(c,d,e) did not work. Im novice to data.table... Lastly,  do you have a good reference for the join you just used or could you explain to me the format? its different than the DT[i,j,by] basics of data.table i've seen.